# "Enter information about your education history from secondary level onwards": Is the word "onwards" inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was filling an application and I came across this sentence:

> Enter information about your education history from secondary level onwards.

I am a bit confused. Do I have to include the secondary level info or not? What does the word "onwards" do here? Does it have an inclusive role, or an exclusive role?

Comment: The term *from* is the key. It means *beginning from* which would be inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *onwards* doesn't do very much here. Without it,

> ... from secondary level.

means start at secondary level (include it) and work forward from there. If secondary level were not required, *from* would be replaced with *after*.

The only possible reason for including *onwards* would be to distinguish the requirement from

> ... backwards from secondary level.

but even that still includes secondary-level education. ***From*** is inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the context, but it sounds to me like it's inclusive. Even if it's not, what harm is there in including it just to be safe?