Can we interpret the word "from" in this question in following two ways
I had one of these questions in an exam which was intended to be a mathematical question somehow made it a grammatical nightmare for me.

The way I interpreted the sentence "Over a period of 16 hours and 12 minutes from the time they first sound together, how many times will they sound simultaneously?" is that we have to start counting after the bell rings first i.e. we should not include the first time the bell rings. Here "from" doesn't literally mean we should count the first bell, rather we should count after the bells first ring/sound together based on the scenario. As the bells have already rung, and we should count how many times will they ring further.
How should I interpret this question. Should I start counting from the first bell or should I start counting after the first bell?
PS: I hope this question fits this community. Also, I am not asking people to solve this mathematical question. Just help me understand the meaning of last sentence.

@YosefBaskin Yeah, it should be clearer considering the exam was for a government official job. So, I too interpreted it that way i.e. counting should start after the bell and should not include it. But most of the other candidates and the answer key says that we must include the first ring. Here i guess people were taking the literal meaning of the word "from" i.e. for example counting from 1 to 100 means we include 1. So, I think that was the logic they applied. But I think one must look at this sentence from a holistic grammatical POV rather than just the word "from" just like you said.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148402/enter-information-about-your-education-history-from-secondary-level-onwards-i is a near-duplicate, 'inclusive(?) from, but there 'secondary level does not need to be considered as punctive (as/treated as a point in time'). // The question is ambiguous, could be salvaged simply by changing 'from' to 'after' or adding 'more' before 'times', and should allow (as the question is presented)  both answers 4 and 5.

... I was once in a situation where I had to mark externally organised maths exams/tests, and this is the sort of problem we addressed at moderators' meetings. I can't see any other decision being reached (and feedback would have got the question emended).

@EdwinAshworth The question in your link had a definitive answer. There the word "from" was to be taken literally. Just like counting from 1 to 100 means we have to include 1. But this question is different in my opinion as we have to take the scenario in here. Here the question says the bells have sounded simultaneously first. And then after a comma (,) the question is asking us to find the number of times it would sound simultaneously. Based on the context the question points towards counting the number of rings after the first ring. But yes they could have made question clearer.

'Literally' is meaningless here. One dictionary definition [indicating the point in time at which a particular process, event, or activity starts.
"the show will run from 10 a.m. to 2 p.m"] clearly uses inclusive from. [ODE courtesy of Google & Textbook]. Similarly CD, M-W, OALD ('He was blind from birth).... The comma changes nothing. One is guessing at a default interpretation.

It could be clearer, but there are a few hints (initially and then ... from the time they first sound) that counting starts after the initial sound and does not include it. I get 4 times, every 4 hours (240 minutes of 3x4x4x5). Including the initial sound would push the answer to 5.

What could .5 of a simultaneous ring possibly be?

@TinfoilHat, I was puzzled by that at first too, but then realised that the full stop there is not a decimal point. Rather "4. 5 times" means that the fourth answer is five times.

Well, dang, that sure makes sense now, @jsw29.

As has already been said in the comments, the question is ambiguous, and should not have appeared in a multiple-choice test in which the answers based on the inclusive and exclusive readings are both offered.

It could be phrased better as at first glance it sounds ambiguous.  However, the first sound is supposed to be excluded.
Re-arranging the words, it says simultaneously from the first time.  It would be unusual to say they sounded simultaneously when they first rang, so I would take it to mean that it excludes the first time.
On balance, I think that if they meant including  the first time, they would have said so.

I do concur with end result i.e. we should count after the first ring only. But the way I came to interpret it was because of the inclusion of the part "from the time they first sound together" and followed by the second part "how many times will they sound simultaneously". That somehow together gives off the idea that one must count after the first ring/sound and not include the first ring/sound.

Why would it be 'unusual to say they sounded simultaneously when they first rang'? Why would it be any more unusual than the opposite interpretation?
